# How to make an alias for a command?

Tags: bash, alias

I want to make an alias for busybox command

```
BB=$(($(busybox)))
```

Comment: That’s a variable. Use the `alias` shell built-in to make an alias. There are a ton of examples if you google “bash alias”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alias BB='busybox'
```

Syntax for creating alias (in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`) is,

`alias <alised command>='<command with options if any>'`

To create an alias for long listing of files in a directory;

`alias ll='ls -l'` in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention your default shell, so let's suppose it's Bash.

If not already created, you should create this file:

```
~/.bash_aliases
```

into which you pour all your aliases like this:

```
### go up n directories

alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='.. && ..'
alias ....='... && ..'
alias .....='... && ...'
```

or another example with `ls` command:

```
### list files and directories

# always use colors; group directories first; show sizes in kibibytes
alias ls='\ls --kibibytes --color=always --group-directories-first'

# short list; only names; ommit hidden items
alias l='ls'

# long list; human readable sizes; ommit hidden items
alias ll='l -lh'

# long list; exact byte sizes; include hidden items
alias lll='l -la'

# long list a directory
alias lld='ll -d'
```

Note, that your code:

> ```
> BB=$(($(busybox)))
> ```

is neither an alias nor a valid command.

```
alias bb='busybox'
```

should do the trick.

For more information about aliases, use a search engine "alias man page".